# Converting data to type Map<String, List<String>>

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a data of this type

```
Availability(
         id: '01',
          timezone: 'Indonesia',
          openingHours: [
            DayOpeningHours(
              isoWeekday: 1,
              open: TimeOfDay(hour: 10, minute: 00),
              close: TimeOfDay(hour: 18, minute: 30),
            ),
            DayOpeningHours(
              isoWeekday: 2,
              open: TimeOfDay(hour: 10, minute: 00),
              close: TimeOfDay(hour: 18, minute: 30),
            ),
            DayOpeningHours(
              isoWeekday: 3,
              open: TimeOfDay(hour: 10, minute: 00),
              close: TimeOfDay(hour: 18, minute: 30),
            ),
            DayOpeningHours(
              isoWeekday: 4,
              open: TimeOfDay(hour: 10, minute: 00),
              close: TimeOfDay(hour: 18, minute: 30),
            ),
            DayOpeningHours(
              isoWeekday: 5,
              open: TimeOfDay(hour: 10, minute: 00),
              close: TimeOfDay(hour: 18, minute: 30),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

I want to convert it to *Map<String, List< String >>*. Currently, on the ui code I hard coded the code this way:

```
openingHours: {
  'Mon': ['10:00 – 18:30'],
  'Tue': ['10:00 – 18:30'],
  'Wed': ['10:00 – 18:30'],
  'Thu': ['10:00 – 18:30'],
  'Fri': ['10:00 – 18:30'],
  'Sat': ['10:00 – 18:30'],
  'Sun': ['10:00 – 18:30'],
},
```

[image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roxzp.png)

in the UI side it looks like this

[image in the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNsro.png)

How do I convert my Availability data to *Map<String, List< String >>*?

This is the `Availability` class

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Availability {
  const Availability({
    this.id,
    this.timezone,
    this.openingHours,
  });

  final String id;
  final String timezone;
  final List<DayOpeningHours> openingHours;

  Availability copyWith({
    String timezone,
    List<DayOpeningHours> openingHours,
  }) {
    return Availability(
      id: id,
      timezone: timezone ?? this.timezone,
      openingHours: openingHours ?? this.openingHours,
    );
  }

  factory Availability.fromJson(
    Map<String, dynamic> json,
  ) =>
      _$AvailabilityFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AvailabilityToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class DayOpeningHours {
  const DayOpeningHours({
    this.isoWeekday,
    this.open,
    this.close,
  });

  final int isoWeekday;

  @JsonKey(
    fromJson: stringToTimeOfDay,
    toJson: timeOfDayToString,
  )
  final TimeOfDay open;

  @JsonKey(
    fromJson: stringToTimeOfDay,
    toJson: timeOfDayToString,
  )
  final TimeOfDay close;

  factory DayOpeningHours.fromJson(
    Map<String, dynamic> json,
  ) =>
      _$DayOpeningHoursFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$DayOpeningHoursToJson(this);
}
```

Comment: Please share the `Availability` class.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I edited my question, I added the class there

Comment: Perhaps you could use reflection with [dart:mirrors](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-mirrors/dart-mirrors-library.html). That would let you iterate over the members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that you were trying to convert the List?
If yes, you can try this:

```
var mapOpeningHours = Map.fromIterable(openingHours, key: (e) => e.isoWeekday, value: (e) => (e.open.toString()+' - '+e.close.toString()));
```

openingHours is your List in Availability.
You will need to do some formatting to the value in your isoWeekday, open and close variables.

**UPDATE**
To make it easier to understand.
This answer assumes that:

1. There is a List of DayOpeningHours in Availability:

   ```
    List<DayOpeningHours> openingHours = [
      DayOpeningHours(
        isoWeekday: 1,
        open: TimeOfDay(hour: 10, minute: 00),
        close: TimeOfDay(hour: 18, minute: 30),
      ),
      DayOpeningHours(
        isoWeekday: 2,
        open: TimeOfDay(hour: 10, minute: 00),
        close: TimeOfDay(hour: 18, minute: 30),
      ),
      DayOpeningHours(
        isoWeekday: 3,
        open: TimeOfDay(hour: 10, minute: 00),
        close: TimeOfDay(hour: 18, minute: 30),
      ),
      DayOpeningHours(
        isoWeekday: 4,
        open: TimeOfDay(hour: 10, minute: 00),
        close: TimeOfDay(hour: 18, minute: 30),
      ),
      DayOpeningHours(
        isoWeekday: 5,
        open: TimeOfDay(hour: 10, minute: 00),
        close: TimeOfDay(hour: 18, minute: 30),
      )
    ];
   ```
2. isoWeekday: 0 is Sunday, isoWeekday: 1 is Monday, isoWeekday: 2 is Tuesday, ..., isoWeekday: 6 is Saturday. Therefore, create a List of String that contains the names of the days:

   ```
    List<String> namesOfDays = [
      'Sunday',
      'Monday',
      'Tuesday',
      'Wednesday',
      'Thursday',
      'Friday',
      'Saturday'
    ];
   ```

Then we can convert the `openingHours` into `mapOpeningHours`

```
    var mapOpeningHours = Map.fromIterable(openingHours,
        key: (e) => namesOfDays[e.isoWeekday],
        value: (e) => (e.open.hour.toString() +
            '.' +
            e.open.minute.toString() +
            ' - ' +
            e.close.hour.toString() +
            '.' +
            e.close.minute.toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create an array of days.

```
final days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
```

Then, create a map using `Map.fromIterable` as shown below.

```
Map<String, List<String>> getMapOfStringList(
      List<DayOpeningHours> listOfOpeningHours) {
    return Map.fromIterable(listOfOpeningHours,
        key: (item) => days[item.isoWeekday - 1],
        value: (item) {
          final openTime = (item.open as TimeOfDay);
          final closeTime = (item.close as TimeOfDay);
          return [
            '${openTime.hour}:${openTime.minute} - ${closeTime.hour}:${closeTime.minute}'
          ];
        });
  }
```

This will return your map as you require. This how should you call this function.

```
final map = getMapOfStringList(
      [
        DayOpeningHours(
          isoWeekday: 1,
          open: TimeOfDay(hour: 10, minute: 00),
          close: TimeOfDay(hour: 18, minute: 30),
        ),
        DayOpeningHours(
          isoWeekday: 2,
          open: TimeOfDay(hour: 10, minute: 00),
          close: TimeOfDay(hour: 18, minute: 30),
        ),
        DayOpeningHours(
          isoWeekday: 3,
          open: TimeOfDay(hour: 10, minute: 00),
          close: TimeOfDay(hour: 18, minute: 30),
        ),
        DayOpeningHours(
          isoWeekday: 4,
          open: TimeOfDay(hour: 10, minute: 00),
          close: TimeOfDay(hour: 18, minute: 30),
        ),
        DayOpeningHours(
          isoWeekday: 5,
          open: TimeOfDay(hour: 10, minute: 00),
          close: TimeOfDay(hour: 18, minute: 30),
        ),
      ],
    );
```